# Rendering Japanese text in Flex

Tags: unicode, flex3, cjk

Flex documentation says that we need to include fonts for Japanese characters, Flash Player can't access fonts from the system in which it is running. If my flex application has to support all languages, should I embed an entire font library into swf-file? In my case data is fed from MySQL, so I can't fall back to runtime loading.

Is there any ttf font equivalent to Arial Unicode MS font?

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flex 4 SDK then it should happen automatically - you just need to define a font fallback chain such as,

```
fontFamily: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro W3","MS GOTHIC","_sans";
```